# arrange/order a geom_boxplot or geom_bar by two other columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to change the order of my x axis for a boxplot. I know I can arrange the plots by reordering the factor used as the x aesthetic. I can do this using values from another column using reorder or forcats::fct_reorder, but how can I reorder using values from two columns? Here is an example dataset:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name,        ~mod, ~dil,
  "LiveGas",     1,    0,
  "DilLiveGas",  1,    3,
  "DilLiveGas1", 1,    1,
  "DeadGas",     0,    0,
  "DilDeadGas",  0,    3,
  "DilDeadGas1", 0,    1
)
```

The order I'd like is as given by `arrange(df, mod, dil)`:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  name          mod   dil
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 DeadGas         0     0
2 DilDeadGas1     0     1
3 DilDeadGas      0     3
4 LiveGas         1     0
5 DilLiveGas1     1     1
6 DilLiveGas      1     3
```

I looked at `forcats::fct_reorder2(df$name, df$dil, df$mod)` but I'm clearly missing something about how this function works.

The real dataset has many more lines with a value field used for generating the boxplot. I can add that if it's helpful, but once I've correctly ordered `name`, that should fall into place.

Comment: Use `interaction(mod, dil)` perhaps?

Comment: `interaction()` gives the correct factor order, but I'm blanking on how to apply these levels to `name`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reorder the factor levels of `name` with your arrangement:

```
namevec <- arrange(df, mod, dil) %>%
  pull(name) 
df$name <- factor(df$name,level = namevec)
```

It should then order the x axis as you want:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(name,dil,fill = as.factor(mod)))+
  geom_col()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This method worked. Because the real dataset has multiple rows for each factor level, I needed to get the unique levels vector as follows: `namevec <- arrange(df, mod, dil) %>% pull(name) %>% unique(). Still looking for a more efficient solution if df is large.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're expecting `forcats::fct_reorder2` to function like you are reordering the factor levels by ordering argument 2 with ties broken with argument 3.

What actually happens is that the function in argument 4 is applied element wise to arguments 2 and 3. Argument 4 must be a function that accepts 2 arguments. The default is `forcats::last2` which is just `.y[order(.x, na.last = FALSE)][length(.y)]`. Overall, not helpful for your usecase.

Instead, I'd suggest base R `base::factor` for this task.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(name, levels = name[order(mod,dil)]),
               y = dil, fill = as.factor(mod))) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = "name", fill = "mod")
```

[image]

Comment: This explanation of fct_reorder2() is much clearer than what's in the forcats docs. I needed to wrap your level generation  bit in unique() to handle multiple rows per factor in my real df like so: factor(name, levels = unique(name[order(mod,dil)])).